# How can I dynamically assign a view using android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to dynamically choose the view based on the device screen size. For most devices i want a list view, but for xlarge screen sizes I want a grid view.

I have created the layouts in two separate library_list.xml files, one in the layout folder and one in the layout-xlarge folder.

The list view looks like:

`ListView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/library_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

and the grid view looks like:

`GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/library_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:columnWidth="@dimen/library_column_width"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/library_item_horizontal_spacing"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

My problem is, in my java code i need to declare a public variable to hold the view and then assign it dynamically.

I tried declaring an AbsListView (I can't declare GridView or ListView because I don't know which one it is until runtime) like this:

`public static AbsListView libraryList;`

...

libraryList = findViewById(R.id.library_list);

which works on an Asus eee transformer tablet, but not samsung galaxy or htc desire (it just crashes, log cat doesn't tell me anything). Is declaring an AbsListView the right way to do it or am I missing something?

I have read through  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but this doesn't seem to help for my problem. This seems like it should be a fairly common scenario but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you declaring libraryList as `static`? That could be your problem right there. See, for example, http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html.

Comment: Okay I will look into that, thank you. As for using the view in java is defining an AbsListView when you don't know what type of view you will be using the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Since both GridView and ListView are derived from AbsListView, it should work without the `static`. If it doesn't, the problem other than how `libraryList` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently older versions of android using setAdapter on absListView throws NoSuchMethodError, so the solution is to cast it first like so:

`if (libraryView instanceof ListView){
    ((ListView)libraryView).setAdapter(listadapter);
}`

else if (libraryView instanceof GridView){
            ((ListView)libraryView).setAdapter(listadapter);
}

Found the answer here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/150653

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you just want to know what the screen size is, so at run time you can make a programmatic decision? One option is to create an xml file that contains a single string resource... create multiples of this file (in values-hdpi, values-ldpi, etc.) with different values but the same ID. Then simply read the string by its ID to determine the screen size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what really what I want. 

Depending on the screen size a different layout and view will be chosen, either a grid view or a list view, both having the same id. I want to be able to programatically manipulate that view, but the problem is I can't assign it to a variable because I don't know what type of view it will be.

Comment: @odiggity - after you set the content, you can `View v = findViewById(id);` to get the view as a base class, and then use the instanceof operator to decide how to handle it. For example, `if (v instanceof ListView) {do_listview_setup();}`

Comment: that's closer but still not what I want. After I get the view I basically just want to 'v.setAdapter()' and 'setOnItemClickListener()', regardless of whether a GridView or ListView are returned. So there is no need to do specific functionality depending on the view returned. But the problem is I can't just do 'View v = findViewById(id); v.setOnItemClickListener()' because setOnItemClickListener() is not defined for View.

Answer (score 0):

Using (if your layout file is called `screen.xml`):

```
setContentView(R.layout.screen);
AbsListView lv = (AbsListView)findViewById(R.id.library_list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

should work on your `onCreate` method: it may seem obvious but make sure you're calling `setContentView` before `findViewById`.

If you're getting a crash because of the assignment then you WILL see something in logcat: if it continues to fail I would advise looking very closely. I would hazard a guess and say that this isn't what is causing the crash: show a more complete chunk of your `onCreate` and we'll probably be able to pin it down.

Comment: Thank you Femi. I am very new to Android dev and I was more or less just wanting to make sure that I was going at it the right way by declaring an AbsListView.

Comment: Ah, glad to be of help. That is actually a neat trick: will have to use that some time.